How do I connect my Azure SQL Database to my Next TS codebase
So I'm building a Next TS project and there is a form that I have made which when users fill will send their data to my Azure SQL database upon clicking the submit button. I'm using Prisma ORM to integrate my code with my database. I initiated Prisma already and built and API route.
This is my API route:
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { z } from "zod";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const bigIntSchema = z.union([
  z.string().regex(/^\d+$/).transform(val => BigInt(val)),
  z.number().int().transform(val => BigInt(val))
]);

const ownerSchema = z.object({
  fullName: z.string().min(1, "Full name is required"),
  phoneNo: z.string().regex(/^[\d\s-+()]*$/, "Invalid phone number format"),
  gymName: z.string().min(1, "Gym name is required"),
  gymAddress: z.string().min(1, "Gym address is required"),
  images: z.string(),
  subscriptionPackages: z.string(),
  gymContactInfo: z.string(),
  workoutsOffered: z.string().optional(),
  equipmentsAvailable: z.string().optional(),
  ledger_start_transaction_id: bigIntSchema,
  ledger_start_sequence_number: bigIntSchema
});

export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const parsedBody = ownerSchema.safeParse(req.body);
  
    if (!parsedBody.success) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid input", errors: parsedBody.error.flatten() });
    }
  
    try {
      const newGymOwner = await prisma.gymOwners.create({
        data: parsedBody.data
      });
  
      return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Gym owner created successfully', data: newGymOwner });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating gym owner:', error);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "Could not create gym owner", error: error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error' });
    } finally {
      await prisma.$disconnect();
    }
}

But whenever I'm testing it on Postman it says 500: Internal Server Error.
Also this is a bit of my form Component:
import AnotherButton from "@/components/buttons/AnotherButton"
import PrimaryButton from "@/components/buttons/PrimaryButton"
import axios from "axios"
import { log } from "console"
import { useState } from "react"


export default function GymOwners() {
    const style = {
        "border": "1px solid black"
    }

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
      fullName: '',
      phoneNumber: '',
      gymName: '',
      gymAddress: '',
      images: '',
      subscriptionPackages: '',
      gymContactInfo: '',
      workoutsOffered: '',
      equipmentsAvailable: '',
    })

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
          const res = await axios.post("http://localhost3000/api/v1/gymowners", formData);
          console.log(res.status)
        } catch(e: any) {
          console.log("Error:", e);
        }

    }

    const handleChange =  (e:  React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      })
    }
    return (
      <div className="flex justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full max-w-3xl border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg p-8 pt-16">
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center text-gray-800 mb-8">
            Create Gym Owner
          </h2>
          <form className="space-y-6">
            <div>
              <label className="block text-lg font-medium text-gray-700">
                Full Name:
                <input
                  className="w-full mt-2 p-3 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  type="text"
                  name="fullName"
                  required
                />


P.S: I'm using Next TS 14

http://localhost3000 isn't a valid URL

Ensure you have configured Azure SQL database correctly in Prisma. Use below connection sting in your .env file to connect Azure SQL database:
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVER_NAME>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<DB_NAME>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false"

Ensure Prisma and Prisma CLI installed correctly. In your  prisma/schema.prisma  file, make sure your model for the  gymOwners  table is correctly set up according to your database schema.
Example  schema.prisma:
datasource db {

  provider = "sqlserver"

  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")

}

generator client {

  provider = "prisma-client-js"

}

model GymOwner {

  id                         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())

  fullName                   String

  phoneNo                    String

  gymName                    String

  gymAddress                 String

  images                     String

  subscriptionPackages       String

  gymContactInfo             String

  workoutsOffered            String?

  equipmentsAvailable        String?

  ledger_start_transaction_id BigInt

  ledger_start_sequence_number BigInt

}

For more information you can refer to the same question in MS Q&A portal.
